# Expand height of @Html.DisplayFor depending on amount of text

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there a way to have a set width but expand the height of a `@Html.DisplayFor` text box? Maybe autowrap the text as needed?

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.description)
```

EB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's depend on your environment.

To put the case that your `@Html.DisplayFor()` is part of the paragraph. Then
you can set width in the paragraph style like below:

```
<p style="width:150px;">    
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.description)                 
</p><br>
```

*Of course it's better to use **internal** or **external** CSS.*

Example of formatting some text with code above:

[image]